# Finding limited expected value of weibull distribution

Tags: probability, statistics

Defining a distribution: $$ F(x) = 1 - \exp(-(x/\beta)^\delta))$$ for $\beta >0 , \delta >0, x >0$.

I am trying to find the limited expected value at a constant $L$. $$LEV(L) = \int_0^L x f(x) dx + L P(X > L)$$

I am struggling with the integral. I have $f(x) = -\dfrac{\delta}{\beta^\delta} x^{\delta -1} \exp(-\dfrac{x^\delta}{\beta^\delta})$ so $$xf(x) = -\dfrac{\delta}{\beta^\delta} x^{\delta} \exp(-\dfrac{x^\delta}{\beta^\delta})$$

But i am not sure how to integrate this.

Answer (score 1):

Let us use the change of variable $t = x^\delta$, thus $x = t^{\frac{1}{\delta}}$ and $d x = \frac{1}{\delta} t^{\frac{1}{\delta}-1} dt$. As a result, the integral (let's denote it as $I$) becomes
$$
I = - \int_0^{L^\delta}{ \frac{\delta}{\beta^\delta} t e^{-\frac{t}{\beta^\delta}} \frac{1}{\delta} t^{\frac{1}{\delta}-1} dt }
$$
$$
I = - \frac{1}{\beta^\delta} 
\int_0^{L^\delta}{ t^{\frac{1}{\delta}+1-1} e^{-\frac{t}{\beta^\delta}} dt }
$$
$$
I = - \frac{1}{\beta^\delta} (\beta^\delta)^{-(\frac{1}{\delta}+1)}
\gamma\bigg( \frac{1}{\delta}+1 ; \frac{L^\delta}{\beta^\delta} \bigg)
$$
$$
I = - \frac{1}{\beta}
\gamma\bigg( \frac{1}{\delta}+1 ; \frac{L^\delta}{\beta^\delta} \bigg),
$$
where $\gamma(a;x)$ is the lower incomplete Gamma function.

If you're looking for the case $L \to \infty$, replace $\gamma(\cdot; \cdot)$ by $\Gamma(\cdot; \cdot)$, which is the upper incomplete Gamma function.

Special property:
$$
\gamma(a;x) + \Gamma(a;x) = \Gamma(a),
$$
where $\Gamma(a)$ is the (normal/complete) Gamma function.